# Responsive Design CSS fills entire screen when using small browser

Tags: css, responsive-design

I'm trying to use responsive css media queries to hide my sidebar unless the screen is large, or is a tablet big enough and in landscape mode. It seems to be working based on resizing my browser, until I get to a certain size it fills the entire screen. I'm using Twitter Bootstrap styles as well, but not the responsive styles so I don't see how that could be a problem.

Is there another media query that I should use? I also tried a `min-width` of 0 and `max-width` of 320, that did not work.

Example:
[image: Working sidebar, fills side and is displayed]
[image: Not working, once reached a certain size it fills entire browser window]

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="span2 sidebar">
        <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")">
            <h3>Link Home</h3>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="span10">
        @RenderBody()
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
html {
    height: 100%;
}

.sidebar {
    background: #333;
    margin: 0;
    padding-left: 1.5em;
    height: 100%;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #888;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px#888;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #888;
    min-height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    font-family: 'Fenix', serif;
    font-weight: 400;
}

/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) {
    /* Styles */
    .sidebar {
        display: none;
    }
}

/* Smartphones (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-width : 321px) {
    /* Styles */
    .sidebar {
        display: none;
    }
}

/* Smartphones (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen and (max-width : 320px) {
    /* Styles */
    .sidebar {
        display: none;
    }
}

/* iPads (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
    /* Styles */
    .sidebar {
        display: none;
    }
}

/* iPads (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (orientation : landscape) {
    /* Styles */
    .sidebar {
        display: block;
    }
}

/* iPads (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (orientation : portrait) {
    /* Styles */
    .sidebar {
        display: none;
    }
}

/* Desktops and laptops ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-width : 1224px) {
    /* Styles */
    .sidebar {
        display: block;
    }
}

/* Large screens ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-width : 1824px) {
    /* Styles */
    .sidebar {
        display: block;
    }
}

/* iPhone 4 ----------- */
@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5), only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5) {
    /* Styles */
    .sidebar {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply use

```css
// Landscape phone to portrait tablet
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .sidebar {
            display: none;
    }
}
```

And why did you not use the responsive css when using twitter bootstrap? There is a class called `.hidden-phone`, very useful.

The most used media querys are

```css
// Large desktop
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
}

// Portrait tablet to landscape and desktop
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) {
}

// Everything below 1024px
@media (max-width: 979px) {
}

// Landscape phone to portrait tablet
@media (max-width: 767px) {
}

// Landscape phones and down
@media (max-width: 480px) {
}
```

Comment: Why I didn't use the css: I didn't even realize there were classes to hide things specifically for phone/tablet. I thought it was just to resize the window as it got smaller....thanks. This was drastically easier.

Answer (score 3):

Bootstrap has [responsive utility classes](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#responsive) to help you do this easily.  Eg .hidden-phone, .visible-desktop

Instead of complicating your life and creating the custom css classes, try something as simple as:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="span2 sidebar hidden-phone">
    <!-- sidebar details -->
    </a>
</div>
<div class="span10">
    <!-- main body -->
</div>
</div>
```

Good luck!